# Storing array data in jsonb field with Rails and Postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, jsonb

Say I have a Car model in which I want to display different kinds of data. I add a `data` column to the table:

```
class AddDataToCars < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :cars, :data, :jsonb, null: false, default: '{}'
    add_index  :cars, :data, using: :gin
  end
end
```

Then I add an accessor for a field I want to be present (`extra_options`):

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  store_accessor :data, :wheel_count, :extra_options

  validates :extra_options, presence: true
end
```

I make sure it's a permitted parameter in `cars_controller.rb`:

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:make, :model, :data, :wheel_count, :extra_options)
end
```

Now I can create a text input in my `_form.html.erb` partial that puts data in `wheel_count` like this:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :wheel_count %>
  <%= f.text_field :wheel_count %>
</div>
```

And it works as expected. What I then would like is a select list (multiple select) or a set of checkboxes where the selected options are stored under `extra_options`.

I've tried with:

```
<%= f.select :extra_options, options_for_select(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], car.extra_options), { include_blank: true }, { multiple: true } %>
```

which produced the following markup:

```
<input name="car[extra_options][]" type="hidden" value="" />     
<select multiple="multiple" name="car[extra_options][]" id="car_extra_options">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Obviously the option labels should make more sense than just 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5, but what's worse is that nothing gets stored when I submit the form.

On submission if I select 2 and 3 the parameters look like:

```
"extra_options"=>["", "2", "3"]
```

which results in the message `Unpermitted parameter: extra_options` so it seems like I am not allowed to put arrays in this field.

It may seem stupid to create a jsonb field just for some extra options but it would naturally also hold all sorts of other data.

So how can I create a multiple select list or preferably a set of checkboxes that saves the data correctly in the jsonb field (and of course when editing a submission shows the already selected/checked items)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, in car_params

```
params.require(:car).permit(:make, :model, :data, :wheel_count, extra_options: [])
```

For checkboxes, try this

```
    <%= hidden_field_tag "car[extra_options][]", [] %>
    <% ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].each do |o| %>
      <% default_checked = car.extra_options.include?(o.to_s) rescue false %>
      <label class="rightpad">
        <%= check_box_tag "car[extra_options][]", o, default_checked %>
      </label>
      <span>
        <%= o %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: That totally works. Would you know how to make it checkboxes instead of a select list. I can't seem to figure out a one-liner like the one above (if it's possible at all).

Comment: Do you happen to know why I cant create a new object this way:
`c = Car.new`
`c.extra_options = [1, 3]`
Am I not supposed to be able to do that?